# E: Unable to locate package python-qt4 with openjdk:13.0.1-debian image

Tags: python, image, docker, pip, debian

I'm trying to build an image with `openjdk:13.0.1-debian` and getting the below error:

```
E: Unable to locate package python-qt4
E: Unable to locate package python-pip
```

Below is the portion of image that I was trying to install.

```
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -o APT::Install-Suggests=0 -o APT::Install-Recommends=0  --no-install-recommends -y \
    python-qt4 \ 
    python-pip \
```

Please help.

Comment: What is the base image?

Comment: debian:sid-slim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because debs python-qt4 and python-pip are not available on sid: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python-qt4

But can be installed with backports. Add buster backports to `sources.list`:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
```

Or just use debian:buster.